# Prove that $f(x) = x - {\lfloor}x{\rfloor}$ is periodic.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, proof-verification, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> How do I prove that $f(x) = x - {\lfloor}x{\rfloor}$ is periodic and find its minimal period?

I've taken the following steps:

Let $x = x_0 + \Delta{x}$ where $x_0 \in \mathbb Z$ and $\Delta{x} \in [0;1)$. I need to prove that for given $x$ and $T$: $f(x) = f(x+T)$ where $T$ is some period to be defined.
Let $T = n + \Delta{T}$ where $n \in \mathbb N$ and $\Delta{T} \in [0, 1)$

$$
f(x) = f(x+T) \\
x- {\lfloor}x{\rfloor} = x+T - {\lfloor}x+T{\rfloor} \\
x_0+\Delta{x} - {\lfloor}x_0+\Delta{x}{\rfloor} = x_0 + \Delta{x} + n +\Delta{T} - {\lfloor}x_0 + \Delta{x} + n + \Delta{T}{\rfloor}
$$

So since $\Delta{x} \in [0;1)$ and $x_0 \in \mathbb Z$ then ${\lfloor}x_0+\Delta{x}{\rfloor} = x_0 +{\lfloor}\Delta{x}{\rfloor}$. Based on that LHS may be rewritten as:

$$
x_0+\Delta{x} - {\lfloor}x_0+\Delta{x}{\rfloor} = \Delta{x} - {\lfloor}\Delta{x}{\rfloor} = \Delta{x}
$$

At the same time:

$$
x_0 + \Delta{x} + n +\Delta{T} - {\lfloor}x_0 + \Delta{x} + n + \Delta{T}{\rfloor} = \\
= (x_0 + n) + \Delta{x} + \Delta{T} - (x_0 + n) - {\lfloor}\Delta{x} + \Delta{T}{\rfloor} = \\
= \Delta{x} + \Delta{T} - {\lfloor}\Delta{x} + \Delta{T}{\rfloor}
$$
That means that for LHS and RHS to be equal $\Delta{T}$ must be equal to $0$, hence $T=n+\Delta{T} \in \mathbb N$. And the smallest natural number is $1$, which gives that the function is indeed periodic and its minimal period is $1$.

Is the proof above valid?

Comment: It's valid, but overkill. $f(x)=f(y)$ iff they have the same fractional part, which happens iff they differ by an integer. Since the integer with smallest nonzero absolute value is 1, it follows that 1 is the minimal period.

Comment: Before trying to prove it's periodic, just ask how in general this function behaves. After you answer that it will be clear what the period is.

Comment: Too long. I didn't read it. $[x+n]=[x]+n;n\in\mathbb Z$ is easy to prove so $f(x+1)=(x+1)-[x+1]=(x+1)-[x]-1=x-[x]=f(x)$ so $f(x)$ has a period of $1$.  If $k<1$; $n-1< x <n-k$ for some integer $n$ then $f(x)=x-n+1$ but $f(x+k)=x+k-n+1$.  So $f$ does not have period $k$. So $1$ is minimum period.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that $$f(x+T) = f(x) \iff x+T - \lfloor x+T\rfloor = x -\lfloor x\rfloor \iff T=\lfloor x+T\rfloor-\lfloor x\rfloor.$$
Since the RHS is the difference of two integers, $T$ must be an integer. Also, $T=\lfloor x+T\rfloor-\lfloor x\rfloor$ for all integers. As such, the minimal period is $T=1$.

Comment: This one is much more elegant than mine, thanks

Comment: I do have to admire the eloquence.

Answer (score 1):

Proof:

$x= \text{floor}(x) + \{x\}$ where ${x}$ denotes the fractional part function.

$\implies f(x)= \{x\}$

$\implies f(x+1)= \{x+1\}$

$\implies f(x+1)=\{x\} $

$\implies f(x)=f(x+1)$.

Thus, $f(x)$ is periodic with period $1$